# MongoDB updateMany with Conditional

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a large DB with various inconsistencies. One of the items I would like to clear up is changing the country status based on the population.

A Sample of the data is:

```
{ "_id" : "D", "name" : "Deutschland", "pop" : 70000000, "country" : "Large Western" }
{ "_id" : "E", "name" : "Eire", "pop" : 4500000, "country" : "Small Western" }
{ "_id" : "G", "name" : "Greenland", "pop" : 30000, "country" : "Dependency" }
{ "_id" : "M", "name" : "Mauritius", "pop" : 1200000, "country" : "Small island"}
{ "_id" : "L", "name" : "Luxembourg", "pop" : 500000, "country" : "Small Principality" }
```

Obviously I would like to change the country field go something more uniform, based on population size.

I've tried this approach, but obviously missing some way of tying into an update of the country field.

```
db.country.updateMany( { case : { $lt : ["$pop" : 20000000] }, then : "Small country" }, { case : { $gte : ["$pop" : 20000000] }, then : "Large country" }
```

Edit: Posted before I was finished writing.

I was thinking to use `$cond` functionality, to basically return if true, do X, if false, do y, while using the updateMany.

Is this possible, or is there a workaround?

Comment: You want `bulkWrite()` using **two** `"updateMany"` statements within it instead. Aggregation expressions cannot be used to do "alternate selection" in any form of `update` statement.

Comment: ````bulkwrite()```` how would I use it here?

Comment: Basically `db.country.bulkWrite([{ "updateMany": { "filter": { "pop": { "$lt": 20000000 } }, "update": { "$set": { "country": "Small Country" } } }},{ "updateMany": { "filter": { "pop": { "$gt": 20000000 } }, "update": { "$set": { "country": "Large Country" } } }}])`. Pretty much as documented on [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-updateonemany)

Comment: FYI [SERVER-6566](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6566) is something that has been around for a long time. It's still not really something anyone is *certain* is really needed, and such requests were made before the "bulk" API was introduced. So there is this and some other features that mitigate various outstanding JIRA issues. Just do **two** writes in the one request rather than "conditionally".

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you. Only new to MongoDB. Was not familiar with Server-6565. Set the code as an answer, and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: You're right. Better as an answer than long comments. I only initially wrote as a comment since I *presumed* a similar answer would already exist. Turns out it does not. Which is a shame, since it would seem a reasonably common problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really want want [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-updateonemany) using two `"updateMany"` statements within it instead. Aggregation expressions cannot be used to do "alternate selection" in any form of update statement.

```
db.country.bulkWrite([
  { "updateMany": {
    "filter": { "pop": { "$lt": 20000000 } },
    "update": { "$set": { "country": "Small Country" } }
  }},
  { "updateMany": {
    "filter": { "pop": { "$gt": 20000000 } },
    "update": { "$set": { "country": "Large Country" } } 
  }}
])
```

There is still an outstanding "feature request" on [SERVER-6566](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6566) for "conditional syntax", but this is not yet resolved. The "bulk" API was actually introduced after this request was raised, and really can be *adapted* as shown to do *more or less* the same thing.

Also using [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) in an aggregation statement as was otherwise suggested is not an option to *"update"* and can only write to a "new collection" at present. The slated change from MongoDB 4.2 onwards would allow [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) to actually *"update"* an existing collection, ***however*** this would only be where the collection to be updated is different from any other collection used within the gathering of data from the aggregation pipeline. So it **is not possible** to use an aggregation pipeline to *update the **same** collection* as what you are reading from.

In short, use [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-updateonemany).